# error when uploading ruby on rails application with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am trying to upload my application in aws created in ruby on rails with capistrano following this [guide](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/20.04) but at the moment of doing "cap production deploy "it shows me the following error:

```
    00:34 passenger:restart
          01 passenger-config restart-app /home/deploy/myapp --ignore-app-not-running
          01 *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger(R) doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
          01 is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:
          01
          01  1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
          01     PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
          01     passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's
          01     --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
          01     environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
          01     and run this command again.
          01  2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
          01     service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
          01     PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
          01     option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
          01     line argument.
    (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
    cap aborted!
    SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@54.333.12.94: passenger-config exit status: 1
    passenger-config stdout: Nothing written
    passenger-config stderr: *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger(R) doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
    is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:
    
     1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
        PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
        passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's
        --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
        environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
        and run this command again.
     2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
        service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
        PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
        option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
        line argument.
    
    
    Caused by:
    SSHKit::Command::Failed: passenger-config exit status: 1
    passenger-config stdout: Nothing written
    passenger-config stderr: *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger(R) doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
    is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:
    
     1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
        PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
        passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's
        --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
        environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
        and run this command again.
     2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
        service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
        PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
        option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
        line argument.
    
    Tasks: TOP => passenger:restart
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@54.333.12.94: passenger-config exit status: 1
    passenger-config stdout: Nothing written
    passenger-config stderr: *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger(R) doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
    is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:
    
     1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
        PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
        passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's
        --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
        environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
        and run this command again.
     2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
        service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
        PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
        option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
        line argument.
    
    
    ** DEPLOY FAILED
    ** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:
    
    
     DEBUG [839db3b4] Running /usr/bin/env passenger -v as deploy@54.333.12.94
    
     DEBUG [839db3b4] Command: cd /home/deploy && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="3.1.2" ; /usr/bin/env passenger -v )
    
     DEBUG [839db3b4]   Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.14
    
     DEBUG [839db3b4] Finished in 0.586 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
    
      INFO [82583b63] Running /usr/bin/env passenger-config restart-app /home/deploy/myapp --ignore-app-not-running as deploy@54.333.12.94
    
     DEBUG [82583b63] Command: cd /home/deploy && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="3.1.2" ; /usr/bin/env passenger-config restart-app /home/deploy/myapp --ignore-app-not-running )
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]   *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger(R) doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]   is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]   
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]    1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       and run this command again.
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]    2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
    
     DEBUG [82583b63]       line argument.
```

what bug could be causing this?

my rails application is simple and is developed in ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.3

I am uploading the application in AWS and I have already added the secret_base_key. and when I installed nginx and modified the file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp with the content that appears in the guide and restarted it did not cause any error, but now if I try to restart it, it tells me the following:

nginx.service is not active, cannot reload.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Apache instead of Nginx, but I believe the solution still applies.

On your server, create the following directory:

```
mkdir /var/run/passenger-instreg
```

Tell Apache (or Nginx) to use this path:

```
# Nginx
# Add this line into: 
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf

passenger_instance_registry_dir /var/run/passenger-instreg;

# Apache
# Add this line into: 
# /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf

PassengerInstanceRegistryDir /var/run/passenger-instreg
```

Then tell Capistrano to use this path as well for passenger-restart:

```
# config/deploy.rb
set :passenger_environment_variables, {
  'PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR' => '/var/run/passenger-instreg'
}
```

And that's it!

The problem is caused by Systemd's PrivateTmp. It creates a "private" /tmp directory that changes at every reboot, so Passenger doesn't know where to find that instance registry. For Apache, you'll find it at a path like below:

```
/tmp/systemd-private-xxxx-apache2.service-xxxx/tmp/passenger.xxxx/
```

You could disable that by setting `PrivateTmp=false` in the service file, but you'd end up with non-private /tmp.

The first solution looks cleaner.

Comment: I confirm the nginx solution worked for me.